# Circuit Breaker does not kick-in on delayed response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, circuit-breaker

I am [self learning](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringMicroServices) Circuit Breaker in Spring Boot Microservice. I have configured my [Circuit Breaker](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringMicroServices/blob/main/CircuitBreaker/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/config/CircuitBreakerConfiguration.java) bean like below:

```
@Bean
public CircuitBreaker countCircuitBreaker() {
    CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
            .slidingWindowType(CircuitBreakerConfig.SlidingWindowType.COUNT_BASED).slidingWindowSize(10)
            .slowCallRateThreshold(65.0f).slowCallDurationThreshold(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).build();
    CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(circuitBreakerConfig);
    CircuitBreaker cb = circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker("AppUsersSearchServiceBasedOnCount");
    return cb;
}
```

And trying to mock the delay like below:

```
try {
    responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(buildUrl(), HttpMethod.GET, null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<AppUser>>() {
            });
    if (responseEntity != null && responseEntity.hasBody()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LOGGER.info("Total time to retrieve results = {}", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
}
```

The View Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/appUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String appUsers(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    Supplier<List<AppUser>> appUsersSupplier = timeCircuitBreaker
            .decorateSupplier(() -> appUserManager.getAllAppUsersFromLibrary());

    LOGGER.info("Going to start calling the REST service with Circuit Breaker");
    List<AppUser> appUsers = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Retrieving appUsers from returned supplier");
            appUsers = appUsersSupplier.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not retrieve appUsers from supplier", e);
        }
    }
    model.addAttribute("appUsers", appUsers);

    return "userslist";
}
```

On my view when I try to get the list of users after approximately 45 seconds (as expected) I get the response back. Whereas I am expecting it to throw `CircuitBreaker 'AppUsersSearchServiceBasedOnCount' is OPEN and does not permit further calls` exception. What am I doing wrong here?

Please let me know if other additional information is required.